# How to cut MP3 without re-encoding? Should i just copy the frames?

Tags: c++, audio, mp3

I need to implement a feature that could transmit parts of a large mp3 file over the TCP/IP in a way that would allow user to listen each part without having the entire file (using libmpg123). I would like to allow users to transmit parts as small as possible without re-encoding the stream. I would like to forget about re-encoding, because i don't want sound quality to degrade with each transmission. Each time i want to cut mp3 i do have the splitting coordinates in samples: "from what sample to what sample", so each time i should translate this to an IDs of an mp3-frames. So my question is:

- Does each mp3 frame has enough information (bps/samplerate/bits-per-sample/channels) to play it without entire mp3-file header just by feeding them to an mp3 decoder?
- Is there any BSD/MIT-licensed small library that could work as mp3 splitter using samples-coordinates and supporting VBR?

Comment: MP3 files have no header. Attributes can vary in every frame in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cut binary file!
The only problem of this solution... problem with Tags

Or try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header

Answer (score 1):

Each mp3 frame is stand-alone, and can survive by itself. So you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Ok, frames can have varying bitrate, but hot varying samplerate, right? So where is information about samplerate? In MP3 header or in each frame too? What if decoder met 1 frame with 22050 and second with 44010?

Comment: Unfortunately, frames are not always independent due to a feature called bit (or byte) reservoir: "In the worst case, 9 input frames may be needed before beeing able to decode one single frame." Source: http://mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html